Inquiry about loading glTF models using Blob URLs in 8th Wall Cloud Editor
I am having trouble displaying a model fetched from an external server as a Blob URL in the gltf-model component of A-Frame and adding it as an a-entity element to the body in the 8th Wall Cloud Editor.
The implementation is as follows:
app.js
...
import {TestAddmodelToBodyComponent} from './scripts/test-setAttribute'
AFRAME.registerComponent('test-setattribute', TestAddmodelToBodyComponent)
...

body.html
<a-scene
  test-setattribute
  renderer="colorManagement: true"
  xrweb="enableVps: true; allowedDevices: any">
  <a-assets>
    ・
    ・
    ・
  </a-assets>
  <a-entity id="model"></a-entity>
</a-scene>

test.tsx
function TestAddmodelToBody(urlPath) {
  const targetentity = document.querySelector('#model')
  const username = '□□'
  const password = '○○'
  const encodedCredentials = btoa(`${username}:${password}`)
  fetch(urlPath, {
    headers: {
      'Authorization': `Basic ${encodedCredentials}`,
    },
  }).then(res => res.blob()).then((blob) => {
    // The blob's type is 'application/octet-stream', so change it to 'model/gltf-binary'.
    const gltfBlob = blob.slice(0, blob.size, 'model/gltf-binary')
    // Generate the Blob URL.
    const blobUrl = window.URL.createObjectURL(gltfBlob)
    // Set the `gltf-model` attribute.
    targetentity.setAttribute('gltf-model', blobUrl)
  })
}

export const TestAddmodelToBodyComponent = {
  async init() {
    TestAddmodelToBody('https://○○')
  },
}

The A-Frame version is 1.5.0.
When I launch a web application with this implementation, the gltf-model component is set to <a-entity id=model></a-entity>.
The problem is that the value of the gltf-model component is empty. Below is the status as confirmed by Chrome's Developer Tools.
<a-entity id="model" gltf-model=""></a-entity>
If anyone has any hints or has resolved a similar issue, I would greatly appreciate your advice.
By the way, implementing this behavior requires a domain name and an SSL certificate. It might be difficult to reproduce the issue immediately.
I discussed this issue with the 8thwall Support Team via email.
Based on that consultation, I decided to consult with the external community because I could not implement what I was told could be done and tried to implement it with the 8thwall Cloud Editor.
Please let me know if you would like to view the exchange. I will publish it here if you contact me and give me permission.

I have solved this problem.
The cause was MIME TYPE and my debugging error.
MIME TYPE is wrong.
Looking at the network log of the 8thwall application, the file that was originally stored in the cloud editor was also a blob url.
The MIEM TYPE as fetched was application/octet, so I changed it to MIME TYPE image/jpeg at that time
Debugging error
My perception: If you check the element with a debug tool, you can see if it is set or not.
Example: <a-entity id=“ar-anim-object2” gltf-model="hogehoge/fa70lab....” animation-mixer=“loop: repeat” shadow=“receive: false” class=“cantap”></a-entity>
Actual behavior: the element is empty in the debug tool, but when the model is displayed, it is working.
Example: <a-entity gltf-model=“” id=“ar-anim-object9” animation-mixer=“” shadow=“” class=“cantap”></a-entity>
